# How do I assign grouped values (per-subject) from one df to another df that's grouped by trial (e.g. repeated rows for each subject)

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, dplyr, data-wrangling

I am using R.

I have two dfs, A and B.

A is grouped by trial, so contains numerous observations for each subject (e.g. reaction times per trial).

B is grouped by subject, so contains just one observation per subject (e.g. self-reported individual difference measures).

I want to transfer the B values so they repeat per participant across trials in A. There are numerous variables I wish to transfer from B to A, so I'm looking for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to use [`dplyr::left_join`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) to do this elegantly.

```
library(dplyr)

C <- A %>%
  left_join(B, by = "subject_id")
```

Comment: I feel silly. Thanks a lot for this! My upvote was recorded but won't show because my reputation's < 15.

Comment: Happy I could help! You can still mark it as the accepted answer to your question :)